# Laravel Eloquent: Store model together with related submodels

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i got the models Exam and Question. Simplified code:

```
class Exam {
    public function questions() {
        return $this->hasMany('Question');
    }
    // ...
}

class Question {
    public function exam() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Exam');
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now i wanna upload a file with exam data. The parser class shall create the exam **without saving it**. Then gradually the questions should be created and added to the exam. At the end everything should be saved in a transaction.

```
class ExamParser {
    $exam = new Exam();
    // ...
    while ($linesRemaining) {
        $question = new Question();
        // ...
        $exam->questions[] = $question;    // something like this?
    }
    $exam->saveTogetherWithQuestions();    // how do i realize this?
}
```

I know basically how to save related models but not how I can just relate them and save the whole construct later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of `Question` first. Then create an `Exam`, and save all questions via `Exam`'s relations. Put all codes in a transaction.

**Updated:** Moved model creation out of transaction execution.

```
$questions = [];
while ($linesRemaining) {
    $question = new Question();
    // ...
    $questions[] = $question;
}

$exam = new Exam();
// ...

DB::transaction(function() {
    $exam->save();
    $exam->questions()->saveMany($questions);
});
```

Important note that you have to save `Exam` before attach `Question` to it. Parent `Exam` must have its own primary key first (by saving itself) to allow attaching success. Otherwise, you will have `Question` saved without parent's id.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
I still had this way in mind but it looks less than perfect for me.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to minimize the transaction code and place only the save operations there?
And what are you doing if there are even a few answers which are related to one question?
Isn't there a way to build the object hierarchy (using members not arrays) first and then save everything in one go?

Comment: You are right. I updated the code to minimize the transaction. As far as I know and from my own experiment, there is no way to do "one go" with Eloquent model. You have to create and save new objects by hierarchy, begin from parent, then create its children and attach them to the parent and so on.

Comment: But to keep the questions in an array and not as a member of exam seems inconsequently to me. If the relationship structure would be more complex you had to create a deep array structure and thats circumstantial. I discovered that you can first create the exam and then collect the questions at the exam with `$exam->questions->add($question);`

Comment: Then you can maybe save them with `$exam->questions()->saveMany($exam->questions);` but it looks wrong. I haven't fully understood the behavior of these dynamic variables like $exam->question.